# How do you create a role in COM+ services in PowerShell v3? my script works in v5 but not in v3

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

The following code works to create a new role in Component Services in PSv5 but in PSv3. Would appreciate any help. (I'm a noob)

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1");
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications") ;
$applications.Populate() ;
$appfilter = "OfficeC2RCom";
$AppID = "{F6B836D9-9A19-4D05-9A19-F6B836D9}";

foreach ($application in $applications){

    if($application.name.substring(0,12) -eq $appfilter){

    $roles = $applications.GetCollection("Roles", $AppID)
    $roles.Populate()

    forEach ($role in $roles){

        if($role.Key -eq "Internet Users"){
            Write-Host $role.Key  "'exists'"
            }

        else{
            Write-Host $role.Key "= DOES NOT CONTAIN '[Internet Users]'"

            }
        
        }

        $newRole = $roles.Add()
        $newRole.value("Name") = "Internet Users"
        $roles.SaveChanges();

        }}
```

result of the above was a new role named "Internet Users" under ComponentServices>Computers>MyComputer>COM+Applications>OfficeC2RCom>Roles

**Edit - when i run the code i've shared here on powershell version 5.1 and above, it works as intended. However, when i run this code on PS version 3.0, no new role is created in Component Services and unfortunately no errors are displayed in the console so it's impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share an exact meaning of _did not work_. Some errors?

Comment: Which Windows version? What is `$applications.Count`? BTW, you could ask at https://serverfault.com/